# Spacing between elements in html

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working in an angular application. I have following code in my html component.
code is as follows::

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pt-4">
        <label class="screen-title">  
          <img class="mr-2" src="./assets/images/icons/complete.svg">
           Title
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"><img src="./assets/images/image.svg" class="mr-1"></div>
                <div class="col-11">
                    Description
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-3">
                <div class="col-1"><img src="./assets/images/image.svg" class="mr-1"></div>
                <div class="col-11">
                     message
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-3">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button>Start</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn-common btn-finished">Button1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-3">
                <button class="btn-common btn-extra-key">Button-2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-3">
                <button class="btn-common btn-another-room text-center" >Button-3</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        <label  pt-5">Message         
        </label>
        <div>
            <img src="./assets/images/image1.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My conainer css is as follows::

```
.container{
 width: 95%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    display: ms-flexbox;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I am facing two problems in this. They are as follows::

1) image.svg in container is coming at extreme left of the container. I just want a bit space from left and then I want image.svg.(immage can be anything like tickmark)
2) Message at last should have image.svg just below that at center. But  it is coming at random places in page.

I  tried using some margin and padding but  didn't got it. If I try using some margin, padding then but get out of container and page becomes messy.

How can correct it?

Answer (score 1):

When you use flex, you can use

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

to add space between elements in the same container.

so look at flex.

Comment: hey  my problem is resolved. could you please delete your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to look at your code at line 41.**
[image]

Reference [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) for information on basic HTML practice. Also you can reference [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) for help with proper styling procedures so you can fix your alignment/spacing issues.

Comment: this is  I just gave as example as cannot post actual code here. I think I did some typo in it while editing

Comment: Is this what your output currently looks?: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56dydk

Comment: hey  my problem is resolved. could you please delete your answer.